# why HTML page retured by server is not rendering in the browser

Tags: html, c++, httpserver

I have created a simple HTTP server, (currently it supports only GET ) which returns an HTML page whenever a GET request is made , but the returned HTML page doesnt render in the browser, I verified that my server is indeed working using CURL and CURL is able to fetch the data . The code can be found below

[GITHUB_LINK](https://github.com/akshayvernekar/simplehttpserver.git)

Below is the output from the curl , you can see that the server is returning the HTML page.

```
$ curl -G "192.168.1.188:8080" --verbose
* Rebuilt URL to: 192.168.1.188:8080/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.1.188...
* Connected to 192.168.1.188 (192.168.1.188) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 192.168.1.188:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<  Content-type: text/html
<  
< <!DOCTYPE html> 
<  <html>
<  <head> 
<  <title>simple server</title> 
<  </head> 
<   <body>
<   <h1>Welcome</h1>
<  <p>Welcome to the server .</p>
<   </body>
<  </html>
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.188 left intact
```

Comment: What do you expect? If software doesn't do what it's supposed to you have to debug it. If you think the generated HTTP contents or HTML isn't conform, why the [tag:c] and [tag:c++]? Even, if you wrote your server in C or C++, that doesn't seem to be your issue -> it's irrelevant. If you think a detail is wrong in your C/C++ code but you don't understand why, please, expose this code. (And, btw. I expect it is _either_ C _or_ C++ code. So, only one of the tags should be applied.)

Comment: Are you sure that browser shows correct response status? cURL is not same as browser request. Do `copy cUrl request` from browser network tab and see then.

Comment: The generated HTML is ok thats why I posted the question as I am clueless why the browser doesnt render the page. Removed the C tag. And you say if software doesnt work you have to debug ? Do you think poople post their questions without debugging ?

Comment: @Justinas yes I am returning 200 OK from the server  if that is what you meant. The browser just shows a blank page when requested .

Comment: Fine, that you could solve your problem. 1.) If you want to address a certain commenter in a comment, please, use `@` and the name. (There is an auto-complete which helps.) 2.) Concerning: _Do you think poople post their questions without debugging ?_ I don't think so, I know. If you scroll through old questions, you will find numerous comments regarding this. ;-) To come around this, just include in your text what you've already done. E.g. something like "I already debugged this step by step. It does what's expected but..." This will cool down emotions of readers... ;-)

Comment: Thinking twice, you even wrote _I verified that my server is indeed working_. So, the hint with debugging might've been inappropriate. However, in this case, the other issue - tag spamming - steps in. Finally, it wasn't a C++ issue you was asking for, was it? (Sorry, for the nitpicking.) I have seen down-voted questions without even a single note - I don't like this. Instead, I'd like to write a comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before sending the HTML page you need to send some headers to the browser. Sending just the content of the file is not enough. Check the structure of a response on the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#HTTP_Responses

Try to access a page from working web-server, look for the headers structure in the browser (using the browser's development tools) and replicate that with your code.

Comment: Thanks for the link , I was missing a CRLF  after the header so the browser wasnt able to differentiate between body and header . Its working now.